# failed to move to parent fragment in nested child navigation component?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, navigation, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using Navigation component in my app with the pattern of single activity and multiple fragments, I had some fragments takes the full device screen and other fragments share it with the bottom navigation component and to achieve that with single activity I used fragment container view in my main activity and for home screens fragments which has navigation fragments I used RootHomeFragment which has another fragment container view with bottom navigation view.
here the full application navigation graph

**(nav_main)**
-->MainActivity has view (main_fragment)--> (SplashFragment - LoginFragment = RootHomeFragment)

**(nav_home)** --> RootHomeFragment has views (home_fragment / bottom navigation view) --> (HomeFragment - SettingFragment)

the problem is in settingFragment, there is an action to logout which redirects me to login screen but I can't do this action, I try to do it with the next code in SettingFragment but the app moves to HomeFragment which is the defaul home destination of nav_home

```
   Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(),R.id.fragment_main)
                    .navigate(R.id.actionGoToLoginFromHome)
```

here is the xml of my nav_main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_main"
    app:startDestination="@id/splashFragment">

    <action android:id="@+id/action_global_login"
        app:destination="@id/loginFragment"/>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/rootHomeFragment"
        android:name="package.main.RootHomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_root_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_root_home">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionGoToLoginFromHome"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
         />

    </fragment>
    
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/splashFragment"
        android:name="package.splash.SplashFragment"
        android:label="fragment_splash"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_splash">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionGoToRootHome"
            app:destination="@id/rootHomeFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionGoToLogin"
            app:destination="@id/loginFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/loginFragment"
        android:name="package.signinup.LoginFragment"
        android:label="fragment_login"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_login">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionGoToRootHomeFromLogin"
            app:destination="@id/rootHomeFragment"
            app:launchSingleTop="true"
            app:popUpTo="@id/splashFragment"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

nav_home xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_home"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="package.main.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/ordersFragment"
        android:name="package.main.OrdersFragment"
        android:label="fragment_orders"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_orders" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/settingFragment"
        android:name="package.main.SettingFragment"
        android:label="fragment_setting"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_setting" >

    </fragment>
</navigation>
```

I tried many solutions from many answers and the worked solution always redirects me to homeFragment even when use liveData and observing it in the RootHomeFragment and try to move from there to the LoginFragment it moves also the RootHomeFramgnet default destination HomeFragment? Any solutions?

Comment: I see, can you show the code you are currently using to show HomeFragment after SplashScreen / Login ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me, that you navigate to the LoginFragment then it immediately navigates back to the HomeFragment.

We need to see what happens in the LoginFragment / it's viewModel.

Comment: the login fragment has only one case to go to home (the case if the user authenticated) and on logout the preference login data cleared and user asked to login again so I think this not the problem especially I tested it well